# Introvert who wants to skip social events

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance, work-time

I loathe going to work events and parties.  It is a complete waste of time and I protest by not participating.  Christmas especially, I refuse to celebrate the sky god and I intend to make my reasons for not going to my supervisor known. Can they fire me for being a non-believer? And will not going to their parties/events ruin my chances for promotion?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by venting or by protesting? Not believing is absolutely ok, not wanting to socialize is also ok, but why do you feel the need to alienate people by actively seeking conflict? Whats your goal?

Comment: Are you required to participate?

Comment: Nothing you write in the question is anything to do with being an introvert.

Answer (score 14):

It is fine to not go, and it’s fine to not want to go. It’s also fine to not believe in the Christian god, or any god. In many places, this won’t get you fired — although it’s true that never socializing might hamper your ability to get promoted.

But **this** is **not** OK:

> i refuse to celebrate the sky god and i intend to make my reasons for not going to my supervisor known.

This is disrespecting other people’s beliefs and/or culture. It doesn’t make you cool, smart or superior; it just makes you a jerk. Keep your opinions — especially ones like this — to yourself, in and out of the workplace.

Comment: And just to add - yes, being a jerk will hurt your chances of promotion.

Answer (score 3):

The vast, vast majority of company Christmas parties are so far divorced from a religious observation of the holidays that thinking in terms of "belief" and "non-belief" is generally beside the point.  Lots of companies refer to end-of-the-year parties as "holiday parties" just to emphasize the lack of religious motivation.  Unless you are part of a particularly fundamentalist religion that objects to anything that can potentially be seen as supporting something called "Christmas", there is probably no "belief" to object to.

It sounds like you simply don't enjoy parties.  That's fine, plenty of people don't.  If you tell you boss that you don't want to go to company events because you don't enjoy them, it's unlikely that they're going to try to force you to go.  Being confrontational and saying that you "refuse to celebrate the sky god" is unlikely to help your position (and will likely only cause people to emphasize the non-religious nature of the party which doesn't sound like the actual source of your issue).

In general across Western countries, an employer can't fire you for, say, declining to attend an obviously religious Christmas party that includes prayers and mangers and whatnot.  An employer can probably legally fire you for deciding that you want to avoid all outside socialization though an employer would be pretty dumb to do so.  It is certainly possible, though, that declining to attend all socialization events will hamper your career by preventing you from building relationships with people that can help your career or by preventing you from hearing about opportunities through the grape vine. It is unlikely that it completely forecloses the possibility of promotion but if there are two people up for a promotion one of whom has had several good conversations with senior management about strategy at various networking events and who is generally liked across the company and one of which has not had those conversations and has a reputation as somewhat "chilly", it's not going to be shocking if the first candidate gets the nod.

Answer (score 3):

> I loathe going to work events and parties.

I know the feeling - I don't like them either and avoid them whenever possible.

> It is a complete waste of time and i protest by not participating.

You, erm.. *protest?* Here's a thought - just.. *don't go?* I'm sure there are lots of people out there who like doing many other things that you consider a waste of time. I doubt you go around protesting against those.

> Christmas especially, i refuse to celebrate the sky god

Christmas parties generally have very little to do with God or religion (unless you consider it something of a celebration of Dionysus I suppose!)

> and i intend to make my reasons for not going to my supervisor known.

Why? Unless you have a particular desire to be a drama-llama for the sake of it I can't see any real reason to do so.

> Can they fire me for being a non-believer?

If you're asking if they can fire you for not believing in a particular God then generally the answer is going to be "no". There are exceptions of course but for the most part your religious beliefs or non-beliefs are your own concern.

> And will not going to their parties/events ruin my chances for promotion?

There's some argument that not going to work social events can harm your chances for promotion, but to be honest it's not going to make a massive difference. Especially if you aren't someone who can fake enjoying this sort of event as you won't get any of the soft benefits that can be had anyway.

On the other hand if you decided to make a big stink out it and how you aren't going out of "protest" that's just going to make you look like a misanthrope/weirdo and is probably going to be pretty detrimental - crucially, because at that point you aren't just someone who doesn't get involved in what your colleagues like to do you're essentially criticising them for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your employer and colleagues, you might either propose something from your side (not the case for an introverted person, huh?) or be valued in a different way. I have a few introverted people in my team, both had really valid reasons not to join particular events, but recently (this year) we found some which play well for both of them and they enjoyed.

By no means would I undervalue these guys, the question which comes to my mind a lot, in this case, is how to make the team feel the same.

Protest is a form of conflict, to my taste. If your boss is an adequate person I would talk to him, but if it ruins your relationship - well, you won't have any bad feelings if you change the job, you did what you could to fix that situation.

Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Social events are important, in the end we are human beings and human beings (most of them) are social creatures.

If you go you will earn some points, this is the true.

But if you don't want to go, just tell them you have some personal things to do in this date, don't let your personal beliefs mix with your professional life.

Your professional life must be separated from your personal life, this is my advice.